# SVN : How to get path of repository knowing its URL?

Tags: backup, svn, repository, path

I'm trying to backup my SVN respository with `svnadmin dump` command. So I must give it the path of my repository which I don't know how to find it. I'm using svn over http.

How can I find this?

FYI: I'm having TortoiseSVN installed too if that could help.

Answer (score 1):

*I guess that you ask about [`svnadmin dump`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svnadmin/c/dump/) because there is no `svn dump` subcommand in Apache Subversion.*

- You can use [`svnrdump` tool](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/reposadmin/maint/#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate.svnrdump) to get the dump over HTTP(S). You will get the dump of all version-history your user account has access to in the repository.
- You must have direct access to the repository on disk to use `svnadmin` (i.e. you have to be an administrator), you can't get a dump via HTTP(S) using `svnadmin dump`.

**NOTE:** Subversion repository dump contains revision history only, it does not include [hook scripts](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/reposadmin/create/#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks), [access rules](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/serverconfig/pathbasedauthz/) or any repository config customizations you might've done.

Comment: Thank's @bahrep I've edited my question ;) what about users and their passwords ? are they backed ? what are hook scripts ?

Comment: @mounaim You have to be server's administrator to get access rules and a list of users and hooks.  If you don't have access to the server that hosts your repos then you can't get them unless you use some shared SVN repo hosting which allows you to get them from some kind of web control panel.

Comment: Unfortunately svnrdump is unavailable in SVN 1.6 which I'm using

Comment: Firstly, SVN 1.6 is unsupported since 2013. Moreover, you don't need your server to be 1.6, it's just about **client-side tools**. `svnrdump` is packaged with all Subversion command-line distributions. Grab one at https://www.visualsvn.com/downloads/